# Font size in exam class header

Tags: header-footer, exam

If I do this:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

    \sffamily
    \doublespacing
    \Large

    \header{English 213}{Practice with word pairs}{Spring 2017}
    %\firstpagefooter{}{}{Over \textrightarrow}



    \vspace{1in}
    \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\dotfill}
    \vspace{0.2in}


    \noindent


    \begin{questions}

    \question Because I was so tired I \fillin on the bed. (lay/laid)

    \end{questions}


\end{document}
```

The font and spacing changes apply only to the body text, not to the header. I can edit each header field individually, like `\header{\sffamily \Large English 213}{\sffamily \Large Practice with word pairs}{\sffamily \Large Spring 2017}`, but that seems awkward. Is there a better way?

Comment: There are no global hooks for the header size/font so your manual way is the way to do it.  You should also add some length to the head size to accommodate your larger font: `\extraheadheight{.5in}` (adjust as needed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand\header[3]{%
  \firstpageheader{\sffamily\Large #1}{\sffamily\Large #2}{\sffamily\Large #3}%
  \runningheader{\sffamily\Large #1}{\sffamily\Large #2}{\sffamily\Large #3}%
}
```

so that all your headers have that formatting.

MWE

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand\header[3]{%
  \firstpageheader{\sffamily\Large #1}{\sffamily\Large #2}{\sffamily\Large #3}%
  \runningheader{\sffamily\Large #1}{\sffamily\Large #2}{\sffamily\Large #3}%
}


\begin{document}

    \sffamily
    \doublespacing
    \Large

    \header{English 213}{Practice with word pairs}{Spring 2017}
    %\firstpagefooter{}{}{Over \textrightarrow}



    \vspace{1in}
    \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\dotfill}
    \vspace{0.2in}


    \noindent


    \begin{questions}

    \question Because I was so tired I \fillin on the bed. (lay/laid)

    \end{questions}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you need the same formatting for footers, also add

```
\renewcommand\footer[3]{%
  \firstpagefooter{\sffamily\Large #1}{\sffamily\Large #2}{\sffamily\Large #3}%
  \runningfooter{\sffamily\Large #1}{\sffamily\Large #2}{\sffamily\Large #3}%
}
```